# Distortion of an exported image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am currently analysing the MODIS datasets (e.g "MODIS/006/MOD16A2") available in Earth Engine, computing mean values for each year. While the original projection of the MODIS datasets is SR-ORG:6974, I understand that when functions like mean() are applied to the image collection, the projection changes to EPSG:4326. This transformation does not concern me greatly as I would then apply a reduceRegions() function over the image using a Feature Collection (grid layer) that was based off the EPGS:4326 projection; aggregating the values within the 1km grid squares.

After converting the Vector (from the reduceRegions) back into an Image, I exported the image into my assets. However, when analysing the exported image, I realised that the exported image does not match the computed image in the Map viewer, resulting in incorrect data input for that grid square.

Hence, I would like to figure out if the issue arises based on the projections of the computations or could it be an issue with the export of data.

[image: Original Computed Image in Earth Engine]

[image: Exported Image in EE Assets]

From the image, that there is an additional layer of white grid squares that were created. This has led to those grid squares holding different values than the original one.

Line of code used:

```
//------------------ Extracting THA Boundary -----------------------------

//  Call ee.FeatureCollection (i.e. vector data) 
var ssea = ee.FeatureCollection('users/jjohanness1992/ssea/ssea-adm0');

//  Filter ee.FeatureCollection only to Southeast Asia
var countrylist = ee.List(['THA']);
var THA = ssea.filter(ee.Filter.inList('GID_0',countrylist)); // Filters to Thailand

Map.centerObject(THA,6);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

var evapotranspirationVis1 = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 300.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};

var evapotranspirationVis2 = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1600.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};

var evapotranspirationVis3 = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 5500.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};

var ET = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD16A2")
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2019-01-01')
  .filterBounds(THA)
  .select('ET')
  .map(function(image) { return image.clip(THA)});

print('ET',ET);
print('Projection of ET:', ET.first().projection());
print('Scale of ET:', ET.first().projection().nominalScale());

Map.addLayer(ET,evapotranspirationVis1,'ET');

var totalET = ET.sum().multiply(0.1); // adjusted for scaling factor
print('Projection of Total ET:',totalET.projection());
print('Scale of Total ET:',totalET.projection().nominalScale());

Map.addLayer(totalET,evapotranspirationVis2,'annual total ET');

// summing up into 1km size
var tha_grid = table;

var stats = totalET.reduceRegions({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.sum(),
  collection:tha_grid,
  scale:463.3127165275
});

var totalET1km = stats.reduceToImage({
  properties: ['sum'],
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});

Map.addLayer(totalET1km,evapotranspirationVis3,'ET_1km');

Export.image.toAsset({
  image:totalET1km,
  description:'THA_TotalAnnualET_2018',
  assetId:'Thailand/ET_Sum/THA_TotalAnnualET_2018',
  scale:926.6254330555,
  region:geometry  
//Here is a geometry that I made myself which is a box over the Thailand region. I've also tried using
//THA.geometry().bounds() but I also get the same results
});
```